# How to combine multiple batches doing same operation on different objects into Single Batch?

Tags: apex, batch

Every Month, we have to reset a flag(of type boolean) on Custom Objects A,B and C. For this, I have written one batch class per object.

**ObjAResetBatch.cls**

```
 public class ObjAResetBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Flag__c FROM A__c WHERE Flag__c = TRUE');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
        List<A__c> objAList = (List<A__c>)scope;
        for(A__c aObj: objAList){
            aObj.Flag__c = FALSE;
        }
        update objAList;        
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

There are two other batch classes that are almost same as above but work on Custom Objects B & C.

Is it possible to combine these three batches into single batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think you can utilize something by introducing a constructor to accept the query and accordingly execute it.

Your common batch class will then look like:

```
public class ObjResetBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    private String query;
    private String sObjectType;

    public ObjResetBatch() {
        ... // default constructor
    }

    public ObjResetBatch(String query, String sObjectType) {
        this.query = query;
        this.sObjectType = sObjectType;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
        if(this.sObjectType == 'A__c') {
            List<A__c> objAList = (List<A__c>)scope;
            for(A__c aObj: objAList){
                aObj.Flag__c = FALSE;
            }
            update objAList;        
        }

        if(this.sObjectType == 'B__c') {
            // do this
        }

        if(this.sObjectType == 'C__c') {
            // do this
        }

    }
}
```

And then, you execute the batches accordingly:

```
Database.executeBatch(new ObjResetBatch('SELECT ... FROM A__c WHERE ...', 'A__c'), 1);
Database.executeBatch(new ObjResetBatch('SELECT ... FROM B__c WHERE ...', 'B__c'), 1);
Database.executeBatch(new ObjResetBatch('SELECT ... FROM C__c WHERE ...', 'C__c'), 1);
```

Note that I haven't really gone into the details of effectively writing all conditions, but this should be a step towards what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks easy. Not sure why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second eye :)

Comment: If the field has the same name regardless of the object type, why not just use something like "for (SObject sobj : scope) { sobj.put('Flag__c', false); } update scope;" and forget all the messing around with typecasting and conditional processing in execute. If the field names are different, pass the field name into the constructor instead of the SObject Type.

Comment: @PhilW You can, if that's the case. As noted in my answer, I have mentioned I haven't gone into effectively writing everything here, but its more of an approach here.

Comment: @JayantDas, yes you have an outline of an approach but you made it more complex than it need be.

Comment: @PhilW I would slightly disagree here. This is rather the *simplest and direct* approach. You are considering only one field here, there could be lot more. And then based on the sobject type, you can have other conditions to take care of. I would say it necessarily depends on case to case here. There are definitely different ways of achieving things.

Comment: Well, considering the requirement "we have to reset a flag(of type boolean) on Custom Objects A,B and C." what I have suggested is the simplest and most direct solution. I'm not trying to future proof against requirement change (I'm taking the agile path).